# Mapping AsciiDoc to a docx Template

Tags: ms-word, xml-parsing, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I have recently been using DefectDoku (A Security Management and Reporting Tool) which outputs reports as AsciiDoc... I want to be able to map the report into my docx template. I've been looking into converting AsciiDoc to XML and then XML map the docx template... Seems a little complicated for me so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The project docToolChain suggests to first convert the AsciiDoc output to DocBook using Asciidoctor, and then convert the output via pandoc to docx.

See this link for more information: https://doctoolchain.github.io/docToolchain/#_converttodocx